# Add production server to Git repository without killing production

Tags: git, magento, github

I'm new to Git, and so far loving what it can do.  I started by making a physical copy of my production server and setting up the staging server, then using any conflicts to determine what to add to the .gitignore. Once that was working I added my first commit and pushed everything to github.  then I set up a blank install for my development server and pulled from github, added the local config and ignored files and then did some testing... and learning along the way.

Now I want to get the production server in on the action, but I can't mess up production.  I made a backup of my public_html dir and then the following:

```
git init
git add remote origin git@github.com:<account>/<repo>.git
git pull origin master
```

Then I had a 500 Server error and quickly restored my public_html from backup.  What did I do? What should I do? Any suggestions?

BTW: I couldn't have gotten this far without Stack - so thanks to all of you!

Comment: It's impossible to answer this question. What's the difference between your working public_html directory and the master branch of your git? There's obviously _something_ that causes the error. If you can't spot it by just looking at the diff, gradually introduce the changes from the git into the production directory and take note when it breaks. The web server's error log should also provide clues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured this out, and it seems a little to simple now that I think about it... Production is actually my "Master" so after adding the .gitignore from the staging server, the following did the trick

```
git init
git add .
git commit -a -m "First Commit of Production Server"
git remote add origin git@github.com:<account>/<repo>.git
git push -f origin master
```

-f forces a push regardless of conflict, etc. Now all the files are synced with Production.